# Passing comma separated variable to remote SSH Session

Tags: shell-script, shell, ssh

I am trying to read comma separated variable in shell script and splitting it like as below

```
while [ -z "$variable" ]
do      printf 'variable: '
        read -r variable
        [ -z "$variable" ] && echo 'Action number cannot be empty; try again.'
done

for i in $(echo ${variable} | sed "s/,/ /g")
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

It gives be output as below

```
abc
def
```

But if i am trying same thing with SSH its not working i am trying as below

```
while [ -z "$variable" ]
do      printf 'variable: '
        read -r variable
        [ -z "$variable" ] && echo 'Action number cannot be empty; try again.'
done

ssh -i my.pem -p 2022 ec2-user@ip-address 'bash -s' << EOF

sudo su - << SUEOF

echo "input $variable"

for i in $(echo ${variable} | sed "s/,/ /g")
do
    echo "$i"
done
SUEOF
EOF
```

But in SSH its not printing the values of input variable i am using echo to check the variable is passing into SSH session and i can see the variable is passing to SSH session

```
variable: abc,def
input abc,def
```

Please help me solving the issue

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, you should consider `^` (upvoting) and tick-mark (accepting) the answer. Judging from your questions history, you have not accepted answers to any of your previous questions

Comment: Why don't you let the remote shell script read the values? Why do you need to first read them, then pass them over `ssh`, parse them and then use them?

Comment: @Kusalananda i tried that but when like below                                              ssh -i my.pem -p 2022 ec2-user@ip-address 'bash -s' << EOF

echo "input $variable"

for i in $(echo ${variable} | sed "s/,/ /g")
do
    echo "$i"
done
EOF

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't write a script that you execute _completely_ on the remote side of the `ssh` connection, as in `ssh -i ... ./myscript.sh`?

Comment: yes i want only one script should perform this action without using any another script

Comment: Note that your current script is two scripts in one though. The here-document is technically a separate script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the `$variable` expansion inside the `ssh` heredoc, is expanded by the local shell on the local machine rather than in the remote shell. Generally, we escape the expansion sequences i.e. variable expansion `$var` as `\$var` and command substitutions as `\$(..)` instead of `$(..)`, if we expect the expansion to happen in the remote shell.

So in your `for` loop, the split on `,` happens with your `sed` command but your `"$i"` expansion will again happen in the local shell which should have been happening in the remote shell. Due to *lack* of appropriate escape sequences, the `echo "$i"` will never see a value in the local shell.

You can get around by marking `$i` as `\$i` so that, its expansion happens remotely. Also the loop `for i in $(echo $variable | sed  sed "s/,/ /g")` is an extremely fragile way to iterate over a list split on de-limiter `,`. Use the shell built-ins, `read` in this case

```
ssh -i my.pem -p 2022 ec2-user@ip-address 'bash -s' <<EOF
echo "input $variable"
IFS="," read -ra split <<<"$variable"
for var in "\${split[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "\$var"
done
EOF
```

Note the usage of escape sequences around the array expansion, `"\${split[@]}"` and the variable `"\$var"` which ensures the expansion of those variables happen remotely and not in the local machine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Inian this solution works perfectly...one last question i was trying to access the $var into variable but i am getting empty variable for example i am trying to create directories mkdir $var but $var value is coming empty

Comment: @Rahul: Did you read through the answer and understand it well enough? Inside the remote shell, the `$var` needs to be accessed as `"\$var"`

Comment: That's very dangerous as the expansion of the `$variable` (by the local shell) ends up interpreted as **code** by the remote shell. Think of the case where `$variable` contains `$(reboot)` for instance. Here, you could pass the shell code as arguments instead of stdin and pass the content of `$variable` over stdin (or an env var with `ssh -o SendEnv`).